# recursively list files ordered by file size in an HDFS folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any script to refer to if I need to recursively list files ordered by file size in an HDFS folder?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bin/hdfs dfs -ls -R / | sort -r -n -k 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @kostya has given an excellent answer, using a little awk can help rearrange the output to improve downstream process

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R ${hdfspath} 2> ${hdfsname}.err \
|awk "{ printf \"%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n\",\$5,\$6,\$3,\$1,\$8; }" \
|sort -rn > hdfs-${hdfsname}.du
```